# Get size of window in maximized version in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get the size a form would have in Maximized windowstate without maximizing it ?

I am doing a snapshot of a map control. I want to maximize the window when doing the snapshot but without the user noticing. It seems that the form windows state doesn't change the form size when it is hidden :

```
this.Hide();
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
// Snapshot but this.Size didn't change
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
this.Show();
```

It works fine when not hiding.

So I'm trying to set the size manually but need to know the Maximized state width and height:

```
// x & y ???    
this.Size = new Size(x,y);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read the [workingarea-screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea%28VS.71%29.aspx) size.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `SuspendLayout()` function to suspend layout updates to your screen. By calling `ResumeLayout()` you can resume this.